# How do I get an empty list's value type?

Tags: c#

I'm not too sure on the terminology of what I'm looking for but..

```
//here's a new list:
List<string> AList = new List<string>();
```

Now how do i get the type of "string" out of the "AList"?

```
/*I cant just ".GetType()" a value within the list since there aren't any values 
and "AList.GetType()" would give me the type of "List<string>".*/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will give you the type of your list

```
List<string> AList = new List<string>();
Type type = AList.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
```

**Output**

```
String
```

[Full Demo Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6niHe0)

---

**Additional Resources**

[Type.GetGenericArguments Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getgenericarguments?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Type_GetGenericArguments)

> Returns an array of Type objects that represent the type arguments of
>   a closed generic type or the type parameters of a generic type
>   definition.

**Returns**

- `Type[]` 
  An array of Type objects that represent the type arguments of a generic type. Returns an empty array if the current type is not a generic type.